# Draw Google map using kml file

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

I want to plot the map of Chicago city like that in http://chicagomap.zolk.com/ . I have downloaded the kml file from the above link. Is there any way to plot this in google map other than parsing the file?

Comment: Use a [**KMLLayer**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#KMLLayers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [KMLLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#KMLLayers) to plot the features of the KML-file

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I had tried KMLLayer.But my kml file was in the localhost.When I uploaded it to a server,I got it working.

Comment: Yes, the KML-file must  be public accessible, because the processing of the file will be handled by google on serverside, not by the browser on clientside.

Comment: Is it possible to add a zoomlevel to the kmllayer?Whatever zoomlevel I had given to the map, the kml layer loads the map to a fixed zoom.

Comment: there is no option to set the zoom, but you may set the preserveViewport-property of the KMLLayer-options to true(what will prevent the viewport of the map from beeing changed when you load the layer). But when you want to have the KML-features inside the viewport, but also want to preserve the initial zoom, observe the status_changed-event of the KMLLayer and reset the zoom of the map back to the initial zoom.